# Any way to profile .NET application to see which objects are still not marked for garbage collection at some point?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Is there a way to set some kind of point on line A, and line B, run a process, and see which memory got allocated and didn't get freed (or didn't get marked to be garbage collected)?  I'm using C#, VS 2015 professional, and the profiler just seems to report on which objects were allocated at runtime, i don't see which objects are still held though.

I see in task manager that not all memory gets deallocated as I expect it to be, and would like a profiler which could tell me which objects are holding the memory.  Even if I can't set point A and point B, is there a way for me to at least see which objects haven't been deallocated (or marked for garbage collection) at the time the process terminates?

I'm open to using VS 2015's profiling feature, or free/paid profiler.

Answer (score 0):

All objects in the snapshot, obtained by a memory profiler, are holding in memory and can't be collected at this point of time. What about getting snapshot at some point of execution you can use [JetBrains dotMemory](https://www.jetbrains.com/dotmemory/) and its [Profiling API](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/dotmemory/Controlling_Profiling_Process_Through_API.html) (may be other profilers also have similar feature, I just don't know).
Then you can see what objects were allocated and not collected between snapshot 1 and 2.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for CLR Profiler or similar memory profiling tools (unlike the common profilers that focus on time)

The links are old and with the upcoming close of CodePlex will probably be migrated, but it is a great tool for your purpose.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650691.aspx

https://clrprofiler.codeplex.com/

https://dzone.com/articles/pinpointing-memory-leaks-clr